# How to avoid hundreds of events in vue child components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have an Object like

```
class Engine {
    id = 0;
    crankRPM: = 200;
    maxRPM = 2400;
    numCylinders = 8;
    maxOilTemp = 125;
    isRunning = false;

    start() { ... }
    stop() { ... }
}
```

Now I want a engine component.

**Vue does not want me to mutate the state of a property in any child component so I now have to do this:**

engine-ui Component definition:

```
<template>
    <card> // Imagine fancy styling here
        {{ engine.id }}
        <input :value="engine.crankRPM" @input="$emit('changeCrankRPM', $event.target.value)"></input>
        <input :value="engine.maxRPM" @input="$emit('changeMaxRPM', $event.target.value)"></input>
        <input :value="engine.numCylinders" @input="$emit('changeMumCylinders', $event.target.value)"></input>
        <input :value="engine.maxOilTemp" @input="$emit('changeMaxOilTemp', $event.target.value)"></input>
        <toggle type="toggle" :value="engine.isRunning" @input="$emit('changeIsRunning', $event.target.value)  </toggle>
    </card>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Engine } from "src/code/Engine";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
    name: "engine-ui",
    props: {
        engine: {
            type: Engine,
            required: true,
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

Usage in parent component:

```
<template>
    ...
    <engine-ui :engine="myEngine" 
        @changeCrankRPM="myEngine.crankRPM = $event.target.value"
        @changeMAxRPM="myEngine.maxRPM = $event.target.value"
        @changeNumCylinders="myEngine.numCylinders = $event.target.value"
        @changeOilTemp="myEngine.maxOilTemp = $event.target.value"
        @changeIsRunning="myEngine.isRunning = $event.target.value"/>
    ...
</template>
```

This is extremely verbose and clunky. If I have another 100 fields in the Engine class, It will become unreadable in every parent component that uses engine-ui as it will be a giant wall of text.

Whats the "right way" to design this?

If I now change the Engine class I have to update the engine-ui component and every occurrence in any parent component because the emits are strings.

Comment: It's Vue 3, isn't it? This should be stated because this is version dependent

Comment: Why are you setting `crankRPM`, `maxRPM`, `numCylinders`, `maxOidTemp` to the same value on `@changeCrankRPM`? This looks like a model design problem. That problem aside, you can definitely reduce template verboseness using `v-on="listeners"`. It would be really helpful if you created a *runnable* [mcve]. It would make it simpler for others to understand the required logic of your model, which is currently not clear at all.

Comment: @EstusFlask Its not particulary vue3. This is the same in vue2

Comment: @tao Thanks for the correction. This ```@changeCrankRPM``` was a c/p error. I think this example shows my problem: When I have 300 engine fields I have 300 events, thus 300x ```@myeventname="myobject.targetField = $event.target.value"```. EVERY TIME I use <engine-ui> somewhere. I don't know what an additional example could make more clear.

Comment: It may be different in 2 because v-model works differently, as well as reactivity in classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example where all you need to do is list the field types. Everything passess through the `update` function. But you need to be careful there and cast the value to the correct type, as native `@input` or `@change` events always return the value as a string.

However, as you can see, this eliminates the verboseness of having an update function for each prop.

It can be easily expanded into rendering custom components for custom input types, should you need to.

```js
const { defineComponent, createApp, toRefs, reactive } = Vue;

class Engine {
  id = 0;
  crankRPM = 200;
  description = 'Some description';
  maxRPM = 2400;
  numCylinders = 8;
  maxOilTemp = 125;
  isRunning = false;
}

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      engine: new Engine(),
      engineFields: [
        { key: 'crankRPM', type: 'number' },
        { key: 'maxRPM', type: 'number' },
        { key: 'description', type: 'text' },
        { key: 'numCylinders', type: 'number' },
        { key: 'maxOilTemp', type: 'number' },
        { key: 'isRunning', type: 'boolean' }
      ]
    })
    const update = ({ value, field }) => {
      state.engine[field.key] = field.type === 'number' ? +value : value;
    };
    return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      update
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="card">
        {{ engine.id }}
        <template v-for="field in engineFields" :key="field.key">
          <label v-if="field.type === 'boolean'">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   :checked="engine[field.key]"
                   @change="update({ value: $event.target.checked, field })">
            {{ field.key }}
          </label>
          <input v-else
                 :type="field.type"
                 :value="engine[field.key]"
                 @input="update({ value: $event.target.value, field })">
          
          <!-- you can have as many input types as you want,
               just replace v-else above with v-else-if and add
               another case (e.g: textarea, custom components, ...) -->
        </template>
    </div>
    <pre v-text="engine" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Template logic can to be reduced to a minimum in order to make the code easy to maintain.

The idiomatic way is to treat `engine` as a single value and implement two-way binding

With `v-model`, it would be:

```
<engine-ui v-model="myEngine"/>
```

and

```
...
<div v-for="(_, field) in modelValue">
  <input v-model="modelValue[field]"/>
...
props: {
    modelValue: Engine
},
```

It's not considered a good practice to mutate a prop because this makes data flow more complex. This can be overcome by emitting cloned `Engine` instance from a child on each fieid change, which can be wasteful. Another way is to keep updates in a parent the same they are now:

```
...
<engine-ui :value="myEngine" @update="onEngineUpdate" />
...
methods: {
    onEngineUpdate({ field, fieldValue }) {
         this.myEngine[field] = fieldValue;
    },
},
...
```

and

```
...
<div v-for="(fieldValue, field) in value">
  <input :value="fieldValue" @input="$emit('update', { field, fieldValue : $event.target.value })" />
...
props: {
    value: Engine
},
...
```